# How to read files with specific type of files from subfolders of a directory in JAVA

Tags: java, file, subdirectory

i want to ask how its possible to read files with (.xxx) type from subfolders that exist in a direcory.

I have a folder that contains subfolders (the number of the subfolders isn't known)

```
  C:\MainFolder  
  contains->           [subFolder_A][subFolder_B]......[subFolder_n]
```

Every subFolder containts plenty of files but one of them has a different type, specifically a (.fingerprint) type.

```
       [subFolder_A]  -->  a.txt , atitle.txt  , afin.fingerprint
       [subFolder_B]  -->  b.txt , btitle.txt  , bfin.fingerprint
             ...............................................
       [subFolder_n]  -->  n.txt , ntitle.txt  , nfin.fingerprint
```

So i want to read each time one of this file to java ...do some functions and then the next one until the C:\MainFolder is fulled scan.

I can read one if i give the path directly to code but i want some tips if anyone knows to take them all with an auto way

```
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\MainFolder\\afin.fingerprint");
        byte[] data;
        byte[] fin;
        try {
             this.data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
             byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
       } catch (Exception e) {....}
          fin=data;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [walk the file tree recursively with a stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-), for example like this:

```
 Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/MainFolder"))
      .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
      .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".fingerprint"))
      .forEach(p -> process(p));
```

Comment: Sorry it's `getFileName` - and process is a method you need to write!

Comment: try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\MainFolder"))
                    .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
                    .filter(p -> p.getFileName().endsWith(".fingerprint"))
                    .forEach(p -> process(p));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }

     static void process(Path p) {
        System.out.println("Found file"+p.getName);
    }     something like that didnt work.. Actually instead of print i will call a function(print is to see if its found)

Comment: when i run the code that i post ahead it run without any warnings but i dont see the filenames that contained in subfolders of Mainfolder [System.out.println("Found file"+p.getName); ]

Comment: @NakosKotsanis Change the second filter to `.filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".fingerprint"))` and it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the subdirectories like this:

```
File directory = new File(//path to directory);
  for(File subdirectory : directory.listFiles()){
    for(File file : Subdirectory.listFiles()){
      if(file.toString().endsWith(".footprint"){
      //doStuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nakos, I've edited the code to start from the main directory. All you'd have to do in this situation is give the first path to your directory of subdirectories. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the subfolders of main folder and scan them in a loop. And for each subfolder, again, You can find all files in it and then filter them as You wish. 
For listing contents of a folder use
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()